# Does Mojo Helpdesk keep support for legacy API?

Tags: mojo

Before starting the maintenance of a project, I'm concerned about the timespan where the mother company (http://www.mojohelpdesk.com) offers support to its legacy version of their time tracking product.

My client is using legacy API v1 and legacy UI v1 and it is painful to update to new v2.

Is there any known (un)official support policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Mojo company:

No, API and UI version 1 are no longer supported (as of september 2015) and may both disappear in 2016.

v2 is currently supported and there is no plan on a future compatibility break